# React button color not changing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My react project button colour set as *primary* but it it shown red colour. I want to set it as blue or primary colour. How should I do that. (I'm run on a tutorial)

here is my Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button as MuiButton} from "@material-ui/core";

export default function Button(props) {

const {text, size, color, variant, onClick}=props

  return (
    <MuiButton variant={variant} size={size} color={color} onClick={onClick}>
      {text}
    </MuiButton>
    
 
  );
}
```

Then here is the Controls.js

```
import Button from "./Button";

const Controls = {
    Button
}

export default Controls;
```

here is button my code in the form,

```
<div>
  <Controls.Button variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" text="Submit"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any `theme` configured in your project? Is there more code to be shared? By what you posted, everything looks fine.

Comment: **No. I did not use any theme. I use a badge on this. It's also have the same problem.**        
_<IconButton>
   <Badge badgeContent = {2} color = "primary">
    <ChatBubbleIcon fontSize="small" />
    </Badge>
</IconButton>_
**Do you have any idea what's wrong.?**

Comment: You need to use a theme if you want to change the theme colors

Comment: I just created a codesandbox with your exact code and it works. So you probably have more code affecting the theme: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-solomon-bywlg

Comment: Thank you very much Bruno Monteiro & I solved my problem now. It is very helpful..  Also Jake I tried it using a theme and it also worked. Thanks.